# Is episode 12.5 in Durarara a filler?

Tags: durarara

I am following the anime through EpisodeCalendar and there is no episode 12.5. Is this episode a filler or part of the original story? (That is, would I miss any part of the story if I skipped this episode?)

Comment: What would you do if I said it's a filler and you should watch it? :>

Comment: Can't say I'm familiar with `episodecalendar` but in my experience, episodes ending with .5 are usually recap episodes, which do not further the plot whatsoever, but serve to summarize a set of previous episodes. The one I remember for sure having one of these was Attack on Titan, which had one in the middle of the series to summarize episodes 1-12 (or maybe 1-13).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Durarara episode 12.5, "[Justice Is Slow But Sure](http://durarara.wikia.com/wiki/Durarara!!_Episode_12.5)" isn't a recap episode. It and [episode 25](http://durarara.wikia.com/wiki/Durarara!!_Episode_25)
are DVD only episodes that actually have some semblence of plot to them (as much plot as you get with Durarara). It's not related to any of the
main plotlines, though, especially the:

> overarching yellow scarves/dollars that's part of the later half of the first season.

So it's kind of a side story. You can treat them as OVAs.